# Samples required for bounded accuracy in mean estimation error for multivariate gaussian

Tags: machine-learning

I'm working through some problems in a high dimensional probability textbook and don't seem to know where to start with this one. Any help would be appreciated!

Assume $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_m$ are i.i.d samples generated from $N(\mu, I_{d\times d})$. How large should $m$ be to make sure that with probability $\geq 1 - \delta$ we have:

a) $|| \frac{1}{m} \sum X_i- \mu ||_2 < \epsilon $

b) $|| \frac{1}{m} \sum X_i- \mu ||_1 < \epsilon $

c) $|| \frac{1}{m} \sum X_i - \mu ||_\infty < \epsilon $

Comment: I deleted my answer. Since you are asking what $\Phi$ means, I think it will help more for you to answer a simpler question first: If $X_i$ are i.i.d. samples generated from $N(\mu,1)$, how large should $m$ be to make sure that with probability $\ge 1-\delta$ we have that $|\frac1m \sum X_i - \mu|<\epsilon$? This answers all of questions a, b, c in the case $d=1$.

Comment: I think it would be $m=\Omega (\frac{\ln\frac{1}{\delta}}{\epsilon^2})$. I think I have the solution for a) and b) but don't really know how to convert the l-infinity norm to $\epsilon$. If we have $max_i(\epsilon) = \epsilon$, then won't it just be $m=\Omega (\frac{\ln\frac{d}{\delta}}{\epsilon^2})$ for c in the higher dimensional case? But that doesn't seem correct..

Comment: That doesn't look right, but it's hard to tell with the $\Omega$. If you provide a fully explicit form for $m$, I can probably find a counterexample to the claim.